# Is Raspberry Pi a good system for a middle schooler to learn to code?

Tags: setup

I have no experience with the Raspberry Pi system, but I have heard a lot of good things about it. My son is interested in learning to code (any kind of coding at this point), and I am wondering if you guys think the system would be a good starting point for this? Obviously, I realize there would some set up involved with the actual computer, but I think he would like that aspect of the system as well.

Can anyone give me their thoughts on how easy the Raspberry Pi system  would be for a middle schooler to use and set up and if you think it would help them learn some aspects of coding?

Comment: Curiously, that's the exact reason why the Raspberry Pi exists.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for this site.  Perhaps have a look at raspberrypi.org or ask on raspberrypi.org/forums

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: This question is off-topic, and you will find hundreds, if not thousands, of relevant articles. What is a "middle schooler"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry pi was developed for these types of situations. It is easy to use. With some basic knowledge of Linux it can be used with more efficiency . Anyone can use this device like any other PC. Raspberry pi 4 has more capabilities than ever. You can do programming and iot projects with this device.